# how to add data to leaflet object for use in .on("click")

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I want to stick some data onto my map object, so that when I click on it I can use it as part of the start up for my dialog. Assuming stopId:val[2] is OK *(it doesnt break but the instructions were to extend, but there isnt an extend method to L.circle so I've just hopefully stuck it in for now)*, how do I reference it ?.

```
                                mapobject=L.circle([Lat,Lon], 1000, {
                                    color: 'green',
                                    fillColor: 'green',
                                    fillOpacity: 1,
      // do I need to extend L.circle in order to so this
                                    stopId : stopId_for_this_station
                                }).addTo(map)
                                .on("click",function(e) {

   // my dialog uses the current value of the accompanying select list to go fetch 
   // the data for the form. so I just need to emulate the act of selecting from 
   // the list and we're ready to go

  //THIS LINE WILL BREAK IT OF COURSE, but how do you get hold of an option value anyway    
        //   $( "#select-StopTimes").val(e.target.stopId);


        $( "#dialog-edit-StopTimes").data("edit_flag",true);
        $( "#dialog-edit-StopTimes").dialog( "open" );
        });
```

Comment: I got something to work by having a global associative array     mapobjectToValue[mapobject]=stopId_for_this_station; which works but is going to bite me back eventually

Comment: of course I needed to go L.stamp(mapobject). It works now but it's still pants.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set `mapobject.data = 'foobar'` and read the value in `e.layer.data`